# Can't figure out why script isn't going any further

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, return

I have this function called `zms_add_bridge` that calls a function called `xmlbuilder`.  `xmlbuilder` creates a global variable called `xml` and populates it with stuff.

When `zms_add_bridge` is called, it prints "here" to say that it's gotten at least that far in the script.  Then, it calls `xmlbuilder`, which prints "xml1" along with the xml output to say that it's at least gotten that far in the script.

The issue is that once xmlbuilder exits and returns to zms_add_bridge, the script seems to die.  `xml` is a global variable, so it should print "yes", but it's not even printing "no".

I even tried to `return xml` at the end of `xmlbuilder` to see if that would work, but it didn't (and even still, that'd be redundant since `xml` was declared globally, wouldn't it?)

Any clues?  I'm lost.

```
def xmlbuilder(requestType,xbra):
        global xmlbuild
        global xmlbuild__request
        global xmlbuild__requestElement
        global xmlbuild__requestElementAttribute
        global xml
        xmlbuild = etree.Element("OSS", attrib={"{"+xsi+"}schemaLocation":schema}, nsmap={'xsi':xsi, None:xmlns})
        xmlbuild__request = etree.SubElement(xmlbuild, "Request")
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "RequestType").text = requestType
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "RequestMode").text = "online"
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "SessionID").text = session_id
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "operName").text = apiUser
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "Version").text = version
        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__request, "Overwrite").text = "false"
        xmlbuild__requestElement = etree.SubElement(xmlbuild, "RequestElement")

        for index, data in xbra.items():
                for key in data:
                        xmlbuild__requestElementAttribute = etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__requestElement, "Attribute")
                        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__requestElementAttribute, "Name").text = "%s" % key
                        etree.SubElement(xmlbuild__requestElementAttribute, "Value").text = "%s" % data[key]
        xml = etree.tostring(xmlbuild, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)


        if debug >= 1:
                print "\nDEBUG: Generated XML for transmission\n"
                print xml
        print "xml1: " + xml

def zms_add_bridge(fsan,vlanId,maxUnicast,secure):
        if debug >= 3:
                print "\nDEBUG: Function: zms_add_bridge\n"
                print "\nDEBUG: Get GPON parameters of ONT\n"

        xbra = defaultdict(list)
        xbra[1] = {'Filter_Type': 'GponOnuPhysical'}
        xbra[2] = {'Filter_Condition': 'Device_Id=' + device_Handle_Id}
        xbra[3] = {'Filter_Condition': 'serialNoVendorId=ZNTS'}
        xbra[4] = {'Filter_Condition': 'serialNoVendorSpecificHex=' + fsan}

        if debug >= 4:
                print "\nDEBUG: Dictionary\n"
                for index, data in xbra.items():
                        for key in data:
                                print "Index: %s: Key: %s, Value: %s" % (index, key,data[key])

        print "here"
        xmlbuilder("list",xbra)
        if xml:
                print "yes"
        else:
                print "no"
```

Output:

```
here
xml1: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<OSS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd">
  <Request>
    <RequestType>list</RequestType>
    <RequestMode>online</RequestMode>
    <SessionID>0.379081153249641</SessionID>
    <operName>boss</operName>
    <Version>2.5.1</Version>
    <Overwrite>false</Overwrite>
  </Request>
  <RequestElement>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Filter_Type</Name>
      <Value>GponOnuPhysical</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Filter_Condition</Name>
      <Value>Device_Id=2</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Filter_Condition</Name>
      <Value>serialNoVendorId=ZNTS</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Filter_Condition</Name>
      <Value>serialNoVendorSpecificHex=03739175</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </RequestElement>
</OSS>
```

Comment: "the script seems to die" how? crash? exit without error? or is this running on a server somewhere you can't get the actual error code?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using global variables in the first place. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to use them here (to be honest, there's rarely a good reason, but I certainly can't see one here). Why not just return the value and assign it to xml in zms_add_bridge?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it exits without an error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman honestly, because I don't know any better :)  I'm pretty green with Python, so I don't know the best ways to do things.  That said, even if I ```return xml``` in ```xmlbuilder```, I'm no better off.  I still don't get as far as my ```if xml:``` check in ```zms_add_bridge```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre even if I wrap it in a try: there's no error returned, like so:

`try:
                xmlbuilder("list",xbra)
        except:
                raise`

Sorry, don't know how to format properly yet in replies :(

Comment: You can use except Exception as e: and then look a e to try and get more info.